# navigation bar changes the height when resize. How can I make it the same height?

Tags: css

`

HOME

SERVICE

ABOUT

TEAM

PRICING

PORTFOLIO

CONTACT

`[full width navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAl8C.png)

[resized navigation bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HlB1o.png)

Comment: add some more code or example reflecting what you want. read how to ask good questions

Comment: Where is your current CSS? What have you tried so far? Ideally, you should provide code to *reproduce* the problem, rather than just an image of the result.

Comment: .navbar-default
    {
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
        border: none;
        box-shadow: 0px 2px 8px 0px rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.08);
        margin: 0 !important;
        padding: 0;     
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-brand
    {
        padding-top: 0px;
        padding-bottom: 0px;
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a
    {
        font-size: 13px;
        font-weight: bold;
        line-height: 22px;
    }
.navbar-default .navbar-nav li a:hover
    {
        color: #be0606;
    }

Answer (score 1):

You can try following.

1. You should reduce the image width in small device
2. You can center the logo of the screen and shift the menu downwards full width.